What kind of reward should I set in q-learning to get values closer to the result I expect?
I'm working on a Q-learning project using OpenAI Gym and PyBullet drones. My goal is to control the height of the drone so that it stays at a height of 1 and remains stable at that point. I'm using discrete actions 0, 1, and 2, which correspond to setting the drone's altitude to [0 0 0 0], [1 1 1 1], and [-1 -1 -1 -1] respectively. Initially, I tried setting the reward as 'reward = (1 - (next_state))**2', but I noticed that the reward and the drone's altitude were inversely proportional, meaning that as the drone descended, the reward increased. When I didn't add any reward function, the drone stayed at a height of 1.5 instead of 1.
the system reward function:
'def _computeReward(self):
    state = self._getDroneStateVector(0)
    ret = max(0, 2 - np.linalg.norm(self.TARGET_POS(state[0:3]))**4)
    return ret'

[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/AB4xE48J.png)
here my get_action() function:
`def get_action(q_values, epsilon):        
    if random.random() > epsilon:
        act = np.argmax(q_values.numpy()[0])
        return act
    else:
        act = random.choice(np.arange(3))
        return act`

and my training loops:
`for i in range(num_episodes):
    state = env.reset()
    state = state[0][0][2]   
    total_points = 0 

    for t in range(max_num_timesteps):
        state_qn = np.expand_dims(state, axis=0)  
        q_values = q_network(state_qn)

        action = utils.get_action(q_values, epsilon)  

        a = np.array([[-1, -1, -1, -1]])
        action = action + a
        action = action.reshape(1, -1)

        next_state, reward, done, info, _ = env.step(action)
        next_state = next_state[0][2]
        #reward = (1 - (next_state))**2

        memory_buffer.append(experience(state, action, reward, next_state, done))
        update = utils.check_update_conditions(t, NUM_STEPS_FOR_UPDATE, memory_buffer)

        if update:
            experiences = utils.get_experiences(memory_buffer)
            agent_learn(experiences, GAMMA)

        state = next_state.copy()
        total_points += reward`

What kind of reward function can I define to correct this situation? Or what can I do?

I am downvoting this question because it's title does not summarize a specific problem, as advised here.

What does the state represent? Also what do the 4 numbers corresponding to each action represent?

The state represents the observation space of the 'hover-aviary-v0' environment. With the line state = state[0][0][2], I'm specifically accessing the height of the drone.
Regarding the actions, each of the four numbers corresponding to each action represents control signals for individual motors of the drone. In this setup, typically, -1 means moving down, 1 means moving up,  and 0 indicates no movement (hovering).
